# Share preferences not accesible via IntentService

Tags: android, service, preferences

I am saving a value in Preference, but it always give me the default value. When the app is opened, I can get the actual value. But when I am getting the value from the `IntentService`, it always give me the default value.

Code for saving the value:

```
prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

Code for reading the value:

```
prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = prefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
```

But if i change file name then its working for some period but afterward again it start giving default value

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving stuff from Shared Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);
String s = sp.getString("key", null); // get "value" from the Shared Preferences
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your access mode from Context.MODE_PRIVATE since you are reading it from outside.
Try
       prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);